# Laplace Operator in $3D$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, laplacian

I am looking to find the radial part of Laplace's operator in three dimensions. I looked up Laplace's operator in spherical coordinates and from there I guess the radial part is: $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} + \frac{2\: \partial}{r\:\partial r}$. Is this correct and is there a better, quicker way to find the radial part?

Comment: Quicker than looking it up? Doubtful :) But yes, if you want the terms of the Laplacian with derivatives wrt the radial component, calculating is the only way (via the chain rule).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is correct and there is a quicker way if you are interested only in the radial part. Let $u(x)=f(|x|)$ be a radially symmetric function. Its gradient is $\nabla u(x)=f'(|x|)\frac{x}{|x|}$. Therefore, the flux of the gradient across the outward-oriented sphere $|x|=r$ is $4\pi r^2 f'(r)$.

Consider the spherical shell $r<|x|<r+h$. Net flux of $\nabla u$ out of this shell is 
$$4\pi (r+h)^2 f'(r+h)-4\pi r^2 f'(r)$$
By the divergence theorem, this is equal to $\iint_{r<|x|<r+h}\Delta u$. Dividing by $h$ and letting $h\to 0$ we obtain 
$$
\iint_{|x|=r} \Delta u(x) =  4\pi (r^2 f'(r))' 
$$
Finally, divide by the area $4\pi r^2$ to find the Laplacian itself: 
$\Delta u(x) =  r^{-2} (r^2 f'(r))' $ where $r=|x|$.

Similarly, in $n$ dimensions the radial part of $\Delta$ is 
$$
r^{1-n} (r^{n-1} u_r)_r = u_{rr}+(n-1)r^{-1}u_r
$$

Comment: This is a nice observation that should be made more often. After all, that's where the $r^{-(n-1)}, r^{n-1}$ terms in $$\Delta u= \frac{1}{r^{n-1}}\partial_r(r^{n-1}\partial_r )+\dots $$ come from.