# Transforming the diffusion equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

We need to transform the diffusion equation : 
$u_t = k(u_{xx} + u_{yy})$
into axisymmetric form : $u_t = k(u_{rr} + \frac{u_{r}}{r})$ ,

I first converted the laplace equation $u_{xx} + u_{yy}$ = 0 into polar co-ordinates , thus , $u_{xx} + u_{yy}$ = $u_{rr} + \frac{u_{r}}{r} + \frac{u_{\theta\theta}}{r^{2}}$ = 0 .
Thus ,  $u_t = k(u_{xx} + u_{yy})$ = $k(u_{rr} + \frac{u_{r}}{r} + \frac{u_{\theta\theta}}{r^{2}})$ , now for **axisymmetric** form is it correct to take **$u_{\theta}$** = 0 , which will make **$u_{\theta\theta}$** = 0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem statement is not worded well. You can't transform the equation $u_t=k(u_{xx}+u_{yy})$ into the form $u_t = k(u_{rr} + \frac{u_{r}}{r})$. It's only under the additional assumption that the *solution* $u$ is axisymmetric that we can  write  $u_t = k(u_{rr} + \frac{u_{r}}{r})$.

So, the process is:

1. Convert the PDE to polar coordinates, $u_t = k(u_{rr} + \frac{u_{r}}{r} + \frac{u_{\theta\theta}}{r^{2}})$
2. Make the assumption that $u$ does not depend on $\theta$
3. Simplify the PDE to $u_t = k(u_{rr} + \frac{u_{r}}{r})$ (since the derivative in $\theta$ is zero).

---

By the way, the conversion of the Laplacian to polar or spherical coordinates gets easier if you only care about axisymmetric functions, as [shown here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1281245/).