# Eigenfunctions of $-\Delta_{S^n}$

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions, spherical-harmonics

I read somewhere that the eigenvalues of the Laplacian $-\Delta_{S^n}$ on the sphere $S^n$ consist of $k^2 + (n - 1)k$, with the corresponding eigenspace $V_k$ consisting of homogeneous harmonic polynomials defined on $\mathbb{R}^{n + 1}$. I was trying to derive this myself, but this is where I got stuck: I can prove that if a function is in $V_k$, then, it is the restriction of a homogeneous harmonic polynomial of degree $k$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n + 1}$, but I cannot prove the converse. That is, I cannot prove that a homogeneous harmonic polynomial of degree $k$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^{n + 1}$ restricted to $S^n$ will be an eigenfunction of $-\Delta_{S^n}$ with eigenvalue $k^2 + (n - 1)k$. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Addendum: I see that if I can prove that a homogeneous harmonic polynomial of degree $k$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n  + 1}$ can be expressed as $r^k \varphi (\omega)$, where $\omega \in S^n$, the rest follows. I am not sure how to claim this.

Comment: Homogeneous means that $f(rx) = r^kf(x)$.  Let $\varphi(\omega) = f(\omega)$.  Then $f(x) = |x|^k f(x/|x|) = |x|^k \varphi(\omega)$

Comment: @TimCarson Good call, it was so trivial, silly me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For completess, here is how the rest goes. The radial part of the Euclidean Laplacian (without minus sign) in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is $r^{-n}(r^n u_r)_r$ ([derived here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1281245/)).  If $u$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $k$, then $u(r\xi)=r^k u(\xi)$ (with $\xi\in S^n$), hence
$$r^{-n}(r^n u_r)_r =- r^{-n}(k r^{n+k-1})' u(\xi) = k(n+k-1)r^{k-2}u(\xi)$$
Since $u$ is harmonic, it follows that 
$
-\Delta_{S^n}u = k(n+k-1) u
$ as claimed.